# Mysql - query performance

Tags: mysql, performance, select, concatenation

I haven't data in my mysql table, so I can't check which sql statement will be faster.

I have table with colums: ID | user1 | user2 | 
table will have about 1 million records and I need to select id_user (int) from column user1 or user2.

First query:

```
SELECT `id`, `data` FROM `table` WHERE `user1` = :id_user OR `user2` = :id_user
```

or second query:

```
SELECT `id`, `data` FROM `table` WHERE concat(user1, '/' user2) LIKE '%:id_user%'
```

Which query will select data faster?

Comment: In concat sample need to wrap id of course, because if I put id 1 I'll get result for ID e.g 12

Comment: Create an index on `user1` and `user2` and then use the first query - Read about [EXPLAIN](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)

Answer (score 4):

Any time you apply a function on one or more columns of the table and use that in the WHERE clause, no index can be used.  In order to get the result, the table will be scanned top to bottom.

You can think of this as a "computed" column.  In order to evaluate the comparison, the DB must "compute" the column, so it is no longer a static column that exists in the database, but more akin to a variable.  In your case, you are combining 2 columns and creating a pseudo column.  For a computed column no index exists, so the database must read the row data, do the computation and then evaluate the comparison.  If you look at the queries using `EXPLAIN` you will see that this query table scans all 1 million rows.

As per the comment, you should have an index on user1 and an index on user2, and the query will be highly performant.

I don't know the application but the implementation with a column name ('user') and an iteration (user1, user2) typically indicates a repeating group that should have been normalized into a many-to-many relationship.

With a structure like that in place you would not have a query with `WHERE user1 = something OR user2 = something`.

Comment: Yeah, the second options suffers from the "Expression on the left side of the equality" syndrome. It prevents the usage of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepand "EXPLAIN" in front of your queries and get more informations about your queries. Even when you have a local database with a low amount of example entries inside your table. It will give some informations about used indexes/keys.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `id`, `data` FROM `table` WHERE `user1` = :id_user OR `user2` = :id_user

EXPLAIN SELECT `id`, `data` FROM `table` WHERE concat(user1, '/' user2) LIKE '%:id_user%'
```

Answer (score 0):

First query faster, of course. Cast id to string, concat, search by string (not index) with "like". I don't know what may be slower that second query.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out; neither of your queries will be efficient.  Here is a workaround:

```
( SELECT `id`, `data` FROM `table` WHERE `user1` = :id_user )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT `id`, `data` FROM `table` WHERE `user2` = :id_user )
```

*and* have these indexes:

```
INDEX(user1)
INDEX(user2)
```

That way, the processing will very quickly perform each `SELECT`, then combine them using `UNION`.

Note, further, if there will be no overlaps (or you don't care), it is faster to use `UNION ALL`.  Saying `UNION DISTINCT` dedups the result of the combined selects.

[*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on indexing.